# Reference algorithmic line numbers using cleveref

Tags: cross-referencing, algorithms, cleveref

consider the following example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,final]{report}

\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{algorithmic}

\Crefname{ALC@unique}{Line}{Lines}

\begin{document}

Tests: 

\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\REQUIRE $x$ and $y$
\ENSURE $|x + y|$
\STATE $z = x + y$
\IF{$z<0$}
\RETURN $-z$\label{l1}
\ELSE
\RETURN $z$
\ENDIF
\end{algorithmic}

cref\{l1\}: \cref{l1}, ref\{l1\}: \ref{l1}

\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\REQUIRE $x$ and $y$
\ENSURE $|x - y|$
\STATE $z = x - y$
\IF{$z<0$}
\RETURN $-z$\label{l2}
\ELSE
\RETURN $z$
\ENDIF
\end{algorithmic}

cref\{l2\}: \cref{l2}, ref\{l2\}: \ref{l2}

\end{document}
```

This will output (apart from the pseudocode):

```
cref{l1}: line 3, ref{l1} 3

cref{l2}: line 9, ref{l2} 3
```

As you will notice, \cref{l2} returns an incorrect line number. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cleveref` only claims to support a limited number of packages and `algorithmic` is not on that list.  However, adding `\setcounter{ALC@unique}{0}` after the beginning of your `algorithmic` enviroments fixes the problem, i.e., writing

```
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\setcounter{ALC@unique}{0}
\REQUIRE $x$ and $y$
```

etc.

I suggest you wrap this up in a new environment, so that you do not have to write it each time.

If you also want `hyperref` to behave properly, then I suggest packaging as follows

```
\documentclass[a4paper,final]{report}

\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\Crefname{ALC@unique}{Line}{Lines}
\newcounter{myalg}
\AtBeginEnvironment{algorithmic}{\refstepcounter{myalg}}
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{ALC@unique}{myalg}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Test 1

\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\REQUIRE $x$ and $y$
\ENSURE $|x + y|$
\STATE $z = x + y$
\IF{$z<0$}
\RETURN $-z$\label{l1}
\ELSE
\RETURN $z$
\ENDIF
\end{algorithmic}

cref\{l1\}: \cref{l1}, ref\{l1\}: \ref{l1}

\vfill

Test 2

\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\REQUIRE $x$ and $y$
\ENSURE $|x - y|$
\STATE $z = x - y$
\IF{$z<0$}
\RETURN $-z$\label{l2}
\ELSE
\RETURN $z$
\ENDIF
\end{algorithmic}

cref\{l2\}: \cref{l2}, ref\{l2\}: \ref{l2}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Actually, `cleveref` 0.18.5 claims to support the `algorithms` package, which ships the `algorithmic` package. But you are correct - it is currently not supported, but will be fixed with 0.18.6 (in development). For now only `algorithmicx` is supported.

Comment: I get `! LaTeX Error: No counter 'ALC@unique' defined`. Is the counter name different in `algpseudocode` package? If it is, how can I find it? Thanks in advance

Comment: @kksagar As far as I can tell the algpseudocode does not need this fix.  Make sure you have updated the packages.

Comment: @Karalga The problem seems to persist in the current versions of cleveref

Comment: I got undefined control sequence for \AtBeginEnvironment and I fixed it by adding \usepackage{etoolbox}

Comment: @Damaru Previously `etoolbox` was loaded by one of the packages, now (since 2020) `\AtBeginEnvironment` is part of core LaTeX.