# Cleveref/hyperref: incorrect link to step in algorithm

Tags: hyperref, algorithms, cleveref, algpseudocode

I am using the `cleveref` and `hyperref` packages. This works well overall, but cross-references to lines in algorithms are incorrect.

I found some other related posts, [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66043/reference-algorithmic-line-numbers-using-cleveref) and [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103085/algorithm2e-cleveref-problem-with-wrong-reference-to-line-numbers). However, solutions given there do not work for me.

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}

%% algorithms
\usepackage[chapter]{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

%% referencing
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}


\begin{document}

\chapter{First chapter}

\begin{algorithm}[!htb]
    \caption{First algorithm}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \State A statement in 1st algorithm 
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}


\chapter{Second chapter}
A reference to a line in \cref{alg:secondalg} \ : \cref{step:insecondalg}

\begin{algorithm}[!htb]
    \caption{Second algorithm} \label{alg:secondalg}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \State A statement in 2nd algorithm \label{step:insecondalg}
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

The `\cref` to the step in second chapter gives the right step number, but its link points to the algorithm in first chapter.

Please provide any solutions / workarounds that you may have.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get a warning:

```
pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{ALG@line.1})
has been already used, duplicate ignored
```

In this case `hyperref` doesn't create a suitable auxiliary counter for the anchors, but you can create it yourself: its name should be `HALG@line` and you want to link its representation to something unique, for instance the representation of the `algorithm` counter.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}

%% algorithms
\usepackage[chapter]{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

%% referencing
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{HALG@line}
\renewcommand{\theHALG@line}{\thealgorithm.\arabic{ALG@line}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\chapter{First chapter}

\begin{algorithm}[!htb]
    \caption{First algorithm}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \State A statement in 1st algorithm 
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}


\chapter{Second chapter}
A reference to a line in \cref{alg:secondalg} \ : \cref{step:insecondalg}

\begin{algorithm}[!htb]
    \caption{Second algorithm} \label{alg:secondalg}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \State A statement in 2nd algorithm \label{step:insecondalg}
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you